# Browser not opening file:/// under localhost

Tags: python, html, localhost, href, internet-explorer-11

I am developing a website that reads the folders and files in client's machine and display in HTML table. All i did was working well. But the issue is i create **href** for files in clients machine and it is **not working** in browser from **localhost**.

However i managed to get an addon for chrome and firefox like Local Explorer, Local link etc. But still i **cant find a solution for Internet Explorer 11**.
Although it is **showing the path in path bar** of IE 11 it is not responding.

Here i give a sample code for one hyperlink with screenshot in IE 11 browser

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print """<html>"""
print """<a href="file:///c:/Users/karthvig/Desktop/IDART/testSW/logs/s006.cfg/1490953346.41/summary.log" target="_blank">test</a>"""
print """</html>"""
```

[Screenshot of file in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L0DV.png)

I use **apache web server** for local host and python as language.

I am newbie and please help with a solution. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

IE disables such navigations:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#file_protocol_nav

Try adding the domain to your trusted sites

Comment: Try moving the file to the apache server directory, then change the link to one relative to your server directory, e.g. `a href="/XXX.log"`

Comment: Sounds good but i am not aware of uploading files to server and linking. is there any tutorial i can read and do??

Comment: you can check this out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html , http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/serving-files

Comment: Thank you!! will try and let you know